# My WordPress loop for posts fails

Tags: wordpress, loops, if-statement, while-loop, adsense

i use that code to post an ad in my homepage every 3 posts but instead of that the ad appears behind the 1st post and it seems like it doesnt recognise the loop at all

```
<div id="mason-layout" class="transitions-enabled fluid">
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'blog' ); ?>
<?php if ($i == 3) { ?> ADHERE <?php } ?>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

any ideas?
thanks

Comment: sorry , the code has these 2 lines also above

Comment: <?php $i = 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing part of your loop.

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Edit: If you want to break the if statement onto multiple lines you'll probably want to use a different syntax. Eg:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        //
        // Post Content here
        //
    } // end while
} // end if
```

Recommended reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: i know , i copy paste it wrong and i missed 2 lines <?php $i = 1; ?> <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>